# Django Csv: Having trouble with writerow

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views, export-to-csv

This is basicly my code:

```
def export_to_excel(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=responds.csv'

    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(["First row", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz"])
    writer.writerow(["Second row", "A", "B", "C", '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```

Everything looks ok, but when I really exported it there is something wrong:

[image: excel]

Everything in just a shell! Why? How so? What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure it is not interpreted as a tsv?

Comment: Please update your question with how `csv` is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Excel, just use `Text to Columns` feature and it will be fine. Or use LibreOffice Calc and it show the text import dialogue.

Comment: Thanks. I checked on office web and its OK there.